# Concatenate txt file contents and/or add break to all

Tags: append, centos, concatenation, text-files

I have a bunch of.txt files that need to be made into one big file that can be read by programs such as Microsoft Excel.

The problem is that the files currently do not have a break at the end of them, so they end up in one long line.

Here's an example of what I have (the numbers represent the line number):

```
1. | first line of txt file
2. | second line
```

Here's what I want to turn that into:

```
1. | first line of txt file
2. | second line
3. |
```

I have around 3000 of these files in a folder, all in the same format. Is there any way to take these files and add a blank line to the end of them all?  I'd like to do this without the need for complicated code, i.e. PHP, etc.. I know there are similar things you can do using the terminal (I'm on CentOS), but if something does specifically what I require I'm missing it.

Comment: Your formatting is confusing - you say it's one line but then show a multi-line example. Also, have you tried a regex for this yet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way to achieve this is with a bash for-loop:

```
for file in *.txt; do
    echo >> "$file"
done
```

This iterates over all `.txt` files in the current directory and appends a newline to each file. It can be written in one line, you only need to add a `;` before the `done`.

Note that `$file` is quoted to handle files with spaces and other funny characters in their names.

If the files are spread across many directories and not all in the same one, you can replace `*.txt` with `**/*.txt` to iterate over all `.txt` files in all subdirectories of the current folder.

---

An alternative way is to use `sed`:

```
sed -i "$ s:$:\n:" *.txt
```

The `-i` flag tells `sed` to edit the files in-place. `$` matches the last line, and then the `s` command substitutes the end of the line (again `$`) with a new line (`\n`), thus appending a line to the end of the file.

Answer (score 2):

Try this snippet:

```
for f in *; do ((cat $f && echo "") > $f.tmp) done && rename -f 's/\.tmp$//' *.tmp
```

- This basically takes any file in the folder (`for f in *; do`).
- Outputs the file on STDOUT (`cat $f`) followed by a newline (`echo ""`)
- and redirects the output into filename.tmp (`> $f.tmp`)
- and then moves the  `*.tmp` files to the original files (`rename -f 's/\.tmp$//' *.tmp`).

**Edit:**
Or even simpler:

```
for f in *; do (echo "" >> $f) done
```

- This basically takes any file in the folder (`for f in *; do`).
- Outputs a newline (`echo ""`)
- and appends it to the file (`>> $f`)